# How can I smooth out my JavaScript animations?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I started with the code at the following address:

http://demos.sixrevisions.com/2010/09/11/demo.html

I updated it to use requestAnimFrame as follows:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();
```

The demo is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XBssp/1/

In my eyes running under Chrome the animation still seems a little blurry at higher speeds.  What further optimizations can I do?

Comment: It looks fine to me in Chrome and Firefox. Can you explain what you mean by "blurry"?

Comment: You can lower the speed @Dai He mean you see it moving like 3 balls in row (Eye illusion)

Comment: To be more specific I'm referring to a ghosting effect. @yotam so this will always be present at higher speeds?

Comment: It seems to be very smooth to me in Chrome as well.  After lowering the dx and dy variables to 2 then that eliminates any sort of visual illusions and I cannot perceive the individual frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/zeTyY/)***

Nice animation, you are very close :)

Few things. First, when you animate, you usually want to have small steps so that the item you are animating is not choppy. Second, make sure that when animating in small steps you do it at high frequency (you got that part covered). Third, when animating an object and collision detection is an issue, make sure you offset the boundary by your object's dimensions.

My demo has changed the first and third note.

```
var dx=4;
var dy=4;
```

and

```
if( x < 20 || x > 280)
dx=-dx;
if( y < 20 || y > 280)
```

I also made the bounding box more clear for the example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by blurry, but steps at 20 pixel will make the animation pretty crude (lower them to make the ball less blurry/"skippy").

In any case, if you want to optimize this code you can adjust the following things:

```
//put this outside the loop, no need to get it everytime
context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');

//record previous position and size and only clear that area
//instead of the complete canvas for each time
context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);

//pre-render this object to an off-screen canvas and use
//drawImage(osCanvas, x, y) instead
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

and of course use `requestAnimationFrame` when available to keep animation in sync with the monitor vblank (eliminates jerks).

But put it inside your main loop.

Here is the result of these optimizations:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/XBssp/6/

Without so many DOM elements and iframe:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/XBssp/6/embedded/result/

You cannot do anything about DOM updates so to reduce the impact of repaints and other events in the event queue, it's advisable to have as few other elements in the same window. Use fixed or absolute positions for the elements if possible, avoid drop shadows and rounded borders.

Source output of optmized approach:

```
function draw() {
    //here we only clear last draw and draw the cached ball
    context.clearRect(oldX - 2, oldY -2 ,dia +4,dia +4);
    context.drawImage(canvas,x, y);

    oldX = x; //store the current x/y as old x/y for next loop
    oldY = y;

    if( x<0 || x>300) dx=-dx;
    if( y<0 || y>300) dy=-dy;

    x+=dx;
    y+=dy;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

//function to create cached ball
function createBall() {
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = dia;
    canvas.height = dia;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle="#0000ff";
    ctx.arc(rad,rad,rad,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.fill();
}

createBall(); //create ball
draw();       //start anim
```